# How can I get Ubuntu (17.04) to recognise/acknowledge my password (WPA Key) for WiFi authenction?

Tags: networking

I have installed 17.04 on my IBM T43 laptop, and it works great, except for one area.

- I cannot connect Wi-Fi, as after being prompted for the passkey, the box simply pops right back up and asks me to enter the passkey again.
- The network signal strength is "strong", so I don't think that's the issue. I even reinstalled Ubuntu and the issue persists.
- The really odd part is that the Wi-Fi worked with no hiccups at all on 16.04

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've had this problem before too on 14.04. It would never connect to an 802.11G network, but it would connect to N or B networks fine. I don't suppose the network in question is G? Also, could you please edit your question to include the output of `lspci -knn`?

Comment: What kind of network are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo nmcli dev wifi list` and tell us which of these you are attempting to connect to.

Comment: *  SSID           MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
   TDSV1000W1119  Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2

Comment: Type of Network: LAN

Comment: panther13@panther13-ThinkPad-T43:~$ lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/PM/GMS/910GML Express Processor to DRAM Controller [8086:2590] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 / Z60t [1014:0575]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller [8086:2592] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 [1014:0582]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915, intelfb
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller [8086:2792] (rev 03)

Comment: Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 / Z60t [1014:0575]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller [8086:2592] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 [1014:0582]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915, intelfb

Comment: 00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller [8086:2792] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 [1014:0582]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2660] (rev 03)
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 3 [8086:2664] (rev 03)
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp

Comment: 00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 3 [8086:2664] (rev 03)
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 [8086:2658] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 [1014:0565]
 Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

Comment: 00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:265c] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 [1014:0566]
 Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev d3)
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller [8086:266e] (rev 03)

Comment: Subsystem: IBM 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller [1014:0567]
 Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0
 Kernel modules: snd_intel8x0
00:1e.3 Modem [0703]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Modem Controller [8086:266d] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Modem Controller [1014:0576]
 Kernel modules: snd_intel8x0m
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:2641] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 [1014:0568]
 Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

Comment: Kernel modules: intel_rng, lpc_ich
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) SATA Controller [8086:2653] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 [1014:056a]
 Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
 Kernel modules: ahci, pata_acpi
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:266a] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 [1014:056b]
 Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5751M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:167d] (rev 11)
 ]

Comment: Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad X41 / Z60t [1014:0577]
 Kernel driver in use: tg3
 Kernel modules: tg3
04:00.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: Texas Instruments PCI1510 PC card Cardbus Controller [104c:ac56]
 Subsystem: IBM ThinkPad R40e [1014:0528]
 Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
 Kernel modules: yenta_socket
04:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection [8086:4220] (rev 05)

Comment: Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection [8086:2711]
 Kernel driver in use: ipw2200
 Kernel modules: ipw2200